# Find largest cycle of 'TRUE' booleans

Tags: python, pandas

> I need to count the largest cycle of 'TRUE' in a boolean

I have a boolean Series with several TRUE sequences. I would like to be able to identify the largest cycle of TRUE values.

E.G: `[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]`

I would like to have the cycle: `[10,14]`

My first approach would be to compare element by element and take the index of each true value. The problem I see with this it's that I'm working with a considerably large dataset so I'm afraid it will take a long time.

Do you guys have any other idea that might work?

Thanks :)

Comment: how do you get `[10,14]` for the example list provided? also why is pandas tagged?

Comment: @anky_91 10 is the index of the start of the longest series, 14 is the end index of the longest series

Comment: @anky_91 No worries, took me a bit to work it out as well hah

Comment: `My first approach would be to compare element by element and take the index of each true value. ` - well, linear is the fastest in this case. If you go through it once, it's the best you can have. Keep max start and end/length, and current start, and when you encounter False, compare length and store new max

Comment: @anky_91 Pandas is tagged because the list of booleans is a pandas series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution with no loops is count consecutive `1` or `True`s and get indices maximal values, last add maximal values for starts of `1`s groups:

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
print (s)

a = s == 1
b = a.cumsum()
c = b.sub(b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)
print (c)
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    2
12    3
13    4
14    5
dtype: int32

m = c.max()
idx = c.index[c == m]
print (idx)
Int64Index([14], dtype='int64')

out = list(zip(idx - m + 1, idx))
print (out)
[(10, 14)]
```

Another idea with `itertools.groupby` - create lists for groups with `1` and enumerate  for counter, then get list with maximim length and get minimal and maximal indices:

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
print (s)

from itertools import groupby
a = [ list(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(s), key= lambda x:x[1]) if key]
print (a)
[[(2, 1), (3, 1)], [(10, 1), (11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1)]]

L=[x[0] for x in max(a, key=len)]
out = [min(L), max(L)]
print (out)
[10, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll have to go through the whole dataset somehow. But you don't need the index of each True value. You just need the index of the final one in the longest streak.

Note that if there's a tie, this will only print the latest one.

```
my_bools = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]

max_streak = 0
cur_streak = 0
max_streak_idx = -1

listlen = len(my_bools)

for x in range(0, listlen):
    if my_bools[x]:
        cur_streak += 1
        if cur_streak > max_streak:
            max_streak_idx = x
            max_streak += 1
    else:
        cur_streak = 0
    print(x, cur_streak, max_streak)

if max_streak_idx == -1:
    print("No trues found")
else:
    print("Start of max = ", max_streak_idx - max_streak + 1, "End of max = ", max_streak_idx)
```

Comment: I prefer this for verbosity, the pandas example is a bit obtuse and hard to understand